# Genealogytree - Move Nodes closer together

Tags: tikz-pgf, genealogytree

**Hi,**
please consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{genealogytree}

\gtrset{%
    processing=tikznode,
    family edges={foreground={black}, background={white}},
    level size=4mm,
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \genealogytree[id suffix=@a]
        {
            child{
                g[phantom]{}
                child{
                    p[id=c1]{B\textsubscript{1}}
                    g{A\textsubscript{1}}
                    c{C\textsubscript{1}}
                }
                child{
                    g{A\textsubscript{2}}
                    p[phantom]{}
                    c{C\textsubscript{1}}
                }
                c{\textbf{Uncle A}} %   <----
            }   
        }
        \genealogytree[id suffix=@b, set position=c1@b at c1@a]{
            child{
                g[phantom]{}
                c{\textbf{Uncle B}} %   <----
                child{
                    p[phantom]{}
                    g{B\textsubscript{2}}
                    c{C\textsubscript{1}}
                }
                child{
                    g[id=c1]{B\textsubscript{1}}
                    p{A\textsubscript{1}}
                    c{C\textsubscript{1}}
                }
            }
        }   
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm trying to move the two outer nodes (Uncle A & B) closer to the middle. I have found many ways to space them further apart, but none the other way around.
What do I have to do to make it work?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution myself.

I changed the respective lines to `c[tikz={xshift=-2cm}]{\textbf{Uncle A}}` and it worked.